# How to display web page in ARKit ios

Tags: ios, arkit

Which spritekit or sceneKit node should I use to display a web page in Arkit? As we usually embed other iOS views in arplane as materials.

Answer (score 1):

I got empty pages containing background color of the loaded site after I tried to directly add  my `WKWebView` instance to my node like this:

```
node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = webView
```

The only way I could show a `WKWebView` content in my ARKit 3D environment was to load the webView, wait for it to fully load and then take a screenshot of the loaded page and add it to my node.

```
class ViewController: UIViewController, ARSCNViewDelegate, WKNavigationDelegate {
    @IBOutlet var sceneView: ARSCNView!
    let webView = WKWebView(frame: CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 500, height: 500), configuration: WKWebViewConfiguration())
    ...

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()
        ...
        webView.navigationDelegate = self
        let url = URL(string: "https://stackoverflow.com")!
        webView.load(URLRequest(url: url))
    }

    // WKWebView delegate method
    func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, didFinish navigation: WKNavigation!) {
        // Page should be loaded by now. However sometimes it took even more to load, so you can use delay and wait more, then take the screenshot.
        let screenshot = webView.screenshot()

        let node = SCNNode()
        node.geometry = SCNPlane(width: 2, height: 2)
        node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.diffuse.contents = screenshot
        node.geometry?.firstMaterial?.isDoubleSided = true
        node.position = SCNVector3(0.1, 0.2, -2)

        self.sceneView.scene.rootNode.addChildNode(node)
    }
}
```

screenshot method for webView:

```
extension WKWebView {
    func screenshot() -> UIImage? {
        UIGraphicsBeginImageContextWithOptions(self.bounds.size, true, 0);
        self.drawHierarchy(in: self.bounds, afterScreenUpdates: true);
        let snapshotImage = UIGraphicsGetImageFromCurrentImageContext();
        UIGraphicsEndImageContext();
        return snapshotImage;
    }
}
```

Comment: I will try this approach now

Comment: UIWebView is deprecated in iOS12, any ideas on getting this content to display on a object in ARKit?

Answer (score 1):

`WKWebView` didn't work well with ARKit. `UIWebView` can show the contents in ARKit.

Comment: This doesn't answer the question at all. Please provide an example of how to actually use UIWebView in ARKit.

Answer (score 0):

SpriteKit is used for 2D views and SceneKit for 3D views, so SpriteKit would be more appropriate. Although you can use 2D planes in 3D

Comment: I have tried diffusing the webKitView as material for arplane.it surely gets the html. But isn't displaying it .

Comment: @EmuMalik does it display a blank view or nothing is rendered?

Comment: @MRFrhn I tried "apple.com" . it just displays that Gray menu bar of apple.com and the rest is just plane white background. But if I long press that white background.it shows the iPhone's copy paste option. So it means that content was loaded but isn't being displayed correctly.

Comment: @EmuMalik have you set your webKitView's frame and content size correctly?

Comment: @MRFrhn no i didn't. I added the webKitView with interface builder so I thought interface builder would do the job . I need do this explicitly?

Comment: @EmuMalik I thought you handled it programmatically. It's handled by interface builder.. does the webView displays correctly in a simple viewController, ignoring ARKit?

Comment: @MRFrhn yes the exact same setup of WebKitview loads it correctly if done without ARkit. Problem arises when done in Arkit.

Comment: @EmuMalik I tried to do it but it looks like you can't display a webView by assigning it to `diffuse.content`. However, I could show the webView by adding it to my sceneView.

Comment: @MRFrhn can u explain a bit more about it. Because I have to display a webpage in a 3d environment.like other nodes.